# Monitoring data transmission in my Wifi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

If I switched on my mobile wifi hotspot secured with a password and then if some intruder tried many passwords to connect to my hotspot.Is there any way I could know the list of incorrect passwords he tried to connect to my hotspot.I would prefer much if some android app is used in getting this.Hope I get an answer.

Comment: "I would prefer much if some android app is used in getting this." Why? What are you trying to achieve?